# Flutter how to generate a time slot list

Tags: flutter

I need to generate a time slot list but i don't know how to do that.

Here is my variables;

```
String startTime = 08:30;
String closeTime = 22:00;
String space = 00:30;
```

I would like to do a list like this

```
[08:30, 09:00, 09:30, .... 21:30, 22:00]
```

So is it possible to do that ?

Thanks for helping people. This is my own solution for now:

```
 List<String> createTimeSlotList(int openinHour, int openingMin,
  int closingHour, int closingMin, int averageTime) {
DateTime startTime = DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month,
    selectedDate.day, openinHour, openingMin, 0);
DateTime endTime = DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month,
    selectedDate.day, closingHour, closingMin, 0);
Duration step = Duration(minutes: averageTime);

List<String> timeSlots = [];

while (startTime.isBefore(endTime)) {
  DateTime timeIncrement = startTime.add(step);
  timeSlots.add(DateFormat.Hm().format(timeIncrement));
  startTime = timeIncrement;
}
print(timeSlots);
return timeSlots;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```dart
void main() {
  String startTime = "08:30";
  String closeTime = "22:00";
  String space = "00:30";

  int? startTimeInMinutes = _getTimeInMinutesSinceMidnight(startTime);
  int? closeTimeInMinutes = _getTimeInMinutesSinceMidnight(closeTime);
  int? spaceInMinutes = _getTimeInMinutesSinceMidnight(space);

  if (startTimeInMinutes == null ||
      closeTimeInMinutes == null ||
      spaceInMinutes == null) {
    print('invalid input');
    return;
  }

  List<String> slots = [];
  for (int i = startTimeInMinutes;
      i <= closeTimeInMinutes;
      i += spaceInMinutes) {
    slots.add(_getTimeInStringForMinutesSinceMidnight(i));
  }

  print(slots);
}

int? _getTimeInMinutesSinceMidnight(String time) {
  final parts = time.split(":");

  if (parts.length != 2) {
    return null;
  }

  final a = int.tryParse(parts[0]);
  final b = int.tryParse(parts[1]);
  if (a == null || b == null) {
    return null;
  }

  return a * 60 + b;
}

String _getTimeInStringForMinutesSinceMidnight(int time) {
  final hours = time ~/ 60;
  final minutes = time % 60;

  formatTime(int val) {
    if (val < 10) {
      return "0$val";
    } else {
      return "$val";
    }
  }

  return "${formatTime(hours)}:${formatTime(minutes)}";
}
```

output
`[08:30, 09:00, 09:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00, 18:30, 19:00, 19:30, 20:00, 20:30, 21:00, 21:30, 22:00]`

Comment: thanks for answering. I added my own solution in the question

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code for you:

```
String startTime = "08:30";
String closeTime = "22:00";
String space = "00:30";
List<String> timeSlots = [];
Duration spaceDuration = Duration(minutes: int.parse(space.split(':')[1]), hours: int.parse(space.split(':')[0]));
TimeOfDay start = TimeOfDay(hour: int.parse(startTime.split(':')[0]), minute: int.parse(startTime.split(':')[1]));
TimeOfDay close = TimeOfDay(hour: int.parse(closeTime.split(':')[0]), minute: int.parse(closeTime.split(':')[1]));

while (start.hour < close.hour || (start.hour == close.hour && start.minute <= close.minute)) {
  timeSlots.add(start.hour.toString().padLeft(2, "0") + ":" + start.minute.toString().padLeft(2, "0"));
  final time = DateTime(0, 0, 0, start.hour, start.minute).add(spaceDuration);
  start = TimeOfDay(hour: time.hour, minute: time.minute);
}

print(timeSlots);
```

This will output:

```
[08:30, 09:00, 09:30, 10:00, 10:30, 11:00, 11:30, 12:00, 12:30, 13:00, 13:30, 14:00, 14:30, 15:00, 15:30, 16:00, 16:30, 17:00, 17:30, 18:00, 18:30, 19:00, 19:30, 20:00, 20:30, 21:00, 21:30, 22:00]
```

Hope this helps!